# Printing Errors to a File in Cocoa/ Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Hello Fellow Computer People!

Anyone willing to help will have my gratitude ;)

Just wondering what is the best approach to printing errors to a file i.e. so that if my executable crashes I can have a record of what happened.

This would be in Cocoa, Objective-C or C.

Thanks,

Eric

PS. I hope my question is not too general or vague. Please let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app crashes, it'll automatically write a crash log to `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`. The crash log will include a lot of useful information, including a stack trace and the registry state. You don't need to do anything to enable this functionality.

For other error messages that don't cause crashes, you can use `NSLog` to write information to the application's log file, which is stored at `~/Library/Logs`. The log messages will be prepended with a timestamp. By default `NSLog` writes to the global console log, but that behavior can be modified by [setting `STDERR_FILENO`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLogv).

Comment: Thanks @mipadi. But I'm assuming that the information at /Logs/CrashReporter will also have info from other apps on the machine which I don't want. Ideally the errors from my app will be on a unique file that my app creates and which I can have the user send to me. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes. There is a separate crash log for each app (actually, each crash for each app) in `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`. By default `NSLog` prints to the global console log, but that can be modified by setting `STDERR_FILENO`.

Comment: You can't *set* `STDERR_FILENO`, because it's a constant. You can, however, dupe another file descriptor onto it, which is how you redirect your own stderr.